# what is the size of String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

Tags: mysql, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to save this instance id in my mysql backend for future use. which mysql datatype is best suited to save this instance id?

I thought of using varchar2, is that good option? Also for that i need the size of token in bytes?

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, varchar 2 (200) size. Unique.

Comment: Where is your source?